# (SOLVED) failed to detect device when first installing flutter in Ubuntu (Linuxmint 21)

Tags: linux, flutter, installation, adb, linux-mint

I installed flutter for the first time, according to the link [Linux Install Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#set-up-the-android-emulator) step by step.

after everything else was ready (android sdk, avd, etc), i tried through avd and it worked. helloworld app can run.

then I want to try on real devices. but before i tried to `flutter doctor` and `flutter device`, apparently my device was not detected and failed

[image: flutter devices & flutter doctor]

phone : Xiaomi Redmi 9, android 10. 
laptop : asus vivobook a412da ryzen 3, 3200. linuxmint 21

my device was detected in `lsusb` and I have input it to `udev`.

[image: udev]

I've checked all usb debugging settings in my device, and set screen timeout always on so I don't want to miss notifications when debugging comes

but still, it didnt work. but still `flutter device` says so.

==== updated ====

The solution turned out to be just changing "Use USB for" when the USB debugging option pop out was activated

[popout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MregI.jpg)

Comment: you also have to enable file transfer. IIRC it defaults to charging in USB.

Comment: oh yeah thank you. it solved in my Redmi !

recently i change in other samsung device that have no option about enable file transfer